# Vue scroll event inside jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm integrating a small vue app inside a jquery mobile site.
What's happening: i'm going for the first time inside the site on the URL of the page that cointains the vue app. Then i scroll and I get the console.log saying "scroll".

If i go to another page and come back to the page containing the vue app OR if i enter the site with a URL to another page and I go to the page with the vue app, I get the console.log saying "applyEvents" but when I scroll I get nothing

```
// app.js
methods: {
    scroll(){
        console.log("scroll")
    },
    applyEvents(){
        console.log("applyEvents")
        jQuery(window).on('scroll', this.scroll);
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.applyEvents()
},
beforeDestroy(){
    console.log("beforeDestroy")
    jQuery(window).off('scroll', this.scroll);
}

// main.js

jQuery(document).ready(() => {
    var vueFeed = null;
    jQuery(window).on("pagebeforehide", (event) => {
        if(vueFeed){
            console.log("destroying")
            vueFeed.$destroy()
        }
    })
    jQuery(window).on("pageshow", (event) => { 
        if(jQuery.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "page-dashboard"){
            vueFeed = new Vue({
                el: '#feed',
                template: '<App/>',
                components: { App }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

// edit
If i go from the console and do $vm.applyEvents() i get the console.log saying "applyEvents" and the scroll works

Comment: 1. Don't wrap jQM events in `.ready()`. 2. Make sure you don't have the events duplicated, especially if jQM's Ajax navigation is enabled.

Comment: i call .off so it's not duplicated. i solved it with replacing jQuery.on with document.addEventListener